# How to declare a table variable in SQL Server 2012 stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but the following problem occurs:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure usp_UpatePriv, Line 1
> Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type tblScreen. Parameter
> or variable '@screen' has an invalid data type.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_UpatePriv, Line 8
> Must declare the table variable "@screen".

This is the stored procedure:

```
create procedure usp_UpatePriv
    @screen tblScreen Readonly
as
    declare @username nvarchar(50)
    declare @prev bit
    declare @idscreen bigint

    declare privlange cursor for
        (select username, idScren, Prev from @screen)

    open privlange

    fetch next from privlange into @username, @idscreen, @prev

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    begin
        update tblScreenPriv 
        set Prev = @prev 
        where Username = @username and idScreen = @idscreen
        
        fetch next from privlange into @username, @idscreen, @prev
    end
    
    close privlange;  
    deallocate privlange;
```

Comment: Is this mssql or mysql? Are you getting this error while running the proc via C# code?

Comment: No. I'm trying to create the procedure in sql server Database

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the Table-Valued Type, and you *should* get rid of the cursor.  EG:

```
create type tblScreen as table(username nvarchar(50), idScren int, Prev bit)
go

create proc usp_UpatePriv
 @screen  tblScreen Readonly
as
begin
        with q as 
        (
          select o.Prev, n.Prev NewPrev
          tblScreenPriv o
          join @screen n
            on o.UserName = n.UserName
           and o.idScreen = n.idScreen
        )
        --select * from q
        update q set Prev = NewPrev;
end
```

Comment: Plus 1 for getting rid of the cursor.